# Rails routes point two post routes to the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make two routes with 'post' so I can use AJAX. I have two different forms which each point to a different method in the Userselections Controller.

The two routes are pointed at two different methods: select and create. The two seem to break each other.

How can I point two posts in the routes to the same controller?

Routes

```
# --- User selections routes ---

  get '/user_selections', to: "userselections#select", as: :user_selections
  post '/user_selections', to: "userselections#select", as: :user_selection_category

  post '/user_selections', to: "userselections#create", as: :new_user_selections

  delete '/user_selections/:id', to: "userselections#destroy", as: :destroy_user_selections
```

Userselections controller

```
class UserselectionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:select, :create, :destroy]

  def select
    @user_selection = UserSelection.new
    @user_selections = UserSelection.all
    @companies = Company.all

    @categories = @companies.map {|z| p z.category}
    @unique_categories = @categories.uniq{|x| p x}

    @test = params[:test]

    policy_scope(Company)
    if params[:query].present?
      @companies = Company.search_by_name_and_category(params[:query])
      authorize @companies
    else
      @companies = Company.all
      authorize @companies
    end

    @selection_array = []
    if @user_selections.present?
      @user_selections.each do |selection|
        @selection_array << selection
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    authorize current_user
    policy_scope(UserSelection)

    @user_selection = UserSelection.new

    user_signed_in? ? @user_selection.user_id = current_user.id : @user_selection.user_id = session[:guest_user_id]
    @user_selection.company_id = params["user_selection"]["company_id"].to_i
    @user_selection.save
  end

  def create
    # Create new user selection
    @companies = Company.all
    @user_selection = UserSelection.new(user_selection_params)
    user_signed_in? ? @user_selection.user_id = current_user.id : @user_selection.user_id = session[:guest_user_id]
    @selection_array = []
    user_signed_in? ? user_selections = UserSelection.where(user_id: current_user.id) : user_selections = UserSelection.where(user_id: session[:guest_user_id])
    if @user_selections.present?
      @user_selections.each do |selection|
        @selection_array << selection
      end
    end

    # Create a list of unselected companies and enable AJAX
    @unselected_companies = []
    @companies.each do |company|
      if @selection_array.include?(company)
        @unselected_companies << company
      end
    end

    authorize @user_selection
    if @user_selection.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to select_path }
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'userselections/select'}
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user_selection = UserSelection.find(params[:id])
    @user_selection.destroy
    authorize @user_selection
    policy_scope(UserSelection)
  end

  private

  def user_selection_params
    params.require(:user_selection).permit(:company_id, :test)
  end
end
```

Comment: The routes need to be different, right now they are both a `post` to `/user_selections`, for your setup to work you have to change one of them and then it should be fine, even something as small as one being `/user_selection` would do it

Comment: Thanks for your help! That would mean that I need to create another controller? Would this always be the case in such a situation?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to create another controller at all.  Just a separate action that you are aiming it to, which you are already doing with the `to:` code that then aims to the `select` action in the controller.  So change that route name so it is unique and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two identical routes that are both POST: `post '/user_selections'`

This part of a route must be unique.

You can have two different routes post to the same controller, no problem, but the *route part* - the part that ends up in the URL of a browser (or JS) must be unique.

if you had something like:

```
 post '/user_selections', to: "userselections#select", as: :user_selection_category
 create '/user_selections', to: "userselections#create", as: :new_user_selections
```

this would be fine as one is post and the other is create.

Note that using `create` on a create action is standard.

otherwise rename the URL part eg:

```
 post '/user_selections/select', to: "userselections#select", as: :user_selection_category
 post '/user_selections', to: "userselections#create", as: :new_user_selections
```

because one is named `'/user_selections/select'` and the other is named `'/user_selections'`